# Exclude mysql upgrade from do-release-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to exclude the MySQL Server 5.6 package from upgrading as part of do-release-upgrade process to Ubuntu 16. I'm running an application that is only compatible with MySQL Server 5.6 but do-release-upgrade is upgrading it to 5.7.

I have excluded all MySQL related packages with apt-mark hold as below:

**apt-mark showhold**

libdbd-mysql-perl

libmysqlclient18

mysql-client-5.6

mysql-client-core-5.6

mysql-common

mysql-common-5.6

mysql-server-5.6

mysql-server-core-5.6

When I run do-release-upgrade, at some point, I get error that hold prevents these packages from being marked as garbage and then I cannot continue with the upgrade.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, Ubuntu 16.04 only provides packages for MySQL 5.7. Which means holding version 5.6 will not allow you to upgrade.

The hold you set is doing exactly as it should; which is preventing it from upgrading MySQL to version 5.7. However, it is also holding back your upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.

During research, I found a link to some information on adding MySQL 5.6 to Ubuntu 16.04: https://makandracards.com/makandra/39899-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-16-04

Perhaps you can dump your database, remove MySQL, upgrade to 16.04, install MySQL 5.6 using the information linked above, then restore your database? Make sure you have a back up just in-case it doesn't work out.

Comment: You were right that U16 only provides packages for MySQL 5.7. It turns out that my application supports MySQL 5.7 after all, so I will not have the chance to test your answer.

Thank you very much for taking the time to reply anyway and that's exactly what I would have done.